# Dependency injection in constructor of controller with using a ControllerFactory in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, controller-factory

I'm developing ASP.NET MVC 5 app. I need to use parameters in controller's constructor. DefaultControllerFactory can't resolve it and i inherited from it my own ControllerFactory:

```
public class ControllerFactoryProvider : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        string controllerType = string.Empty;
        IController controller = null;

        // Read Controller Class & Assembly Name from Web.Config
        controllerType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[controllerName];

        if (controllerType == null)
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Assembly not configured for controller " + controllerName);
        // Create Controller Instance
        IDataTransmitter _dataTransmitter = new DataTransmitter();
        controller = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(controllerType), _dataTransmitter) as IController;
        return controller;
    }

    public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
    //This is a sample implementation
    //If pooling is used to write code to return the object to pool
        if (controller is IDisposable)
        {
            (controller as IDisposable).Dispose();
        }
        controller = null;
    }
```

}
I registered it in Global.asax:

> ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new
>   ControllerFactoryProvider());

But when i run my app it whatever use DefaultControllerFactory didn't see constructor with parameters.

Where can i have an error?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Add parameters to your controllers' constructor? or do you intend to do some other kind of logic in the resolution of your controllers?

Comment: I need just set parameters to controllers.

Comment: In that case you don't need to override your controller factory, you just need to plug in your preferred dependency injection container, I'll post an answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, there is no need to override your controller factory. You just need to plug in your preferred dependency injection container.

I haven't had the opportunity to work with every dependency injection containers for [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) but I'll try to give an objective answer.

## [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)

To set up `Ninject` in an `asp.net Mvc 5` project is very straight forward.

### Installing the nuget package

There's a very handy `nuget package` called [`Ninject.MVC5`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/).

You can install it:

- Using the `manage nuget packages` dialogue, or
- By running `Install-Package Ninject.MVC5` in the package manager console.

After installing `Ninject.MVC5` you will see a new file in your solution in `App_Start/` called `NinjectWebCommon.cs`. [Here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/nuget-webhost/Content/App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs.pp) you can see what the contents of that file will end up being.

### Wiring up your dependencies

Now that the package is installed you want to register your denpencies using ninject's api.

Let's say you have an `IFoo` interface and its implementation `Foo`

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Bar()
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Bar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your `NinjectWebCommon` class you're going to tell `ninject` how to resolve an `IFoo` interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
}
```

Keep in mind that by default Ninject has [implicit self binding of concrete types](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject#skipping-the-type-binding-bit--implicit-self-binding-of-concrete-types), that means that

> If the type you’re resolving is a concrete type (like Foo above), Ninject will automatically create a default association via a mechanism called implicit self binding. It’s as if there’s a registration like this:
>
> ```
> Bind<Foo>().To<Foo>();
> ```